# Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours 6th Ed. Chap. 20 ConfigWriter.java error

Tags: java, file-io, runtime-error

Sams Teach Yourself Java in 24 Hours Sixth Edition by Rogers Cadenhead Chapter 20 `ConfigWriter.java` error

I am a Java beginner. I am going through the Java book listed in the title of this post. I am super stumped at how this cannot work. The code is supposed to create a file called `program.properties` and put the text in lines 10 through 12 in it.

```
import java.io.*;

class ConfigWriter {
String newline = System.getProperty("line.separator");

ConfigWriter() {
    try {
        File file = new File("program.properties");
        FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        write(fileStream, "username=max");
        write(fileStream, "score=12550");
        write(fileStream, "level=5");
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.out.println("Could not write file");
    }
}

void write(FileOutputStream stream, String output)
    throws IOException {

    output = output + newline;
    byte[] data = output.getBytes();
    stream.write(data, 0, data.length);
}

public static void main(String[] arguments) {
    ConfigWriter cw = new ConfigWriter();
}
```

}

Instead it does absolutely nothing. Its completely blank. I would most appreciate any help at all with this error!

Comment: 1) *"Caden Ratcliff"*  Don't include sigs. in questions. 2) `FileOutputStream fileStream`  This stream should be flushed & closed.  3) Use the [`Properties`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) API for this type of functionality, or maybe that is chapter 21.

Comment: Just tested it, it wrote fine even without the `close();`. So I can confirm what @Russell says.

Comment: @AndrewThompson - Since this is not a buffered stream, a flush / close won't change anything.  The `stream.write` call will actually write data to the file, and not return until the data has (at least) been delivered to the OS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely problem is that you are confused about where the file will be written.

If you write to a file using a relative pathname (like "program.properties"), Java will attempt to open / create the file in the application's "current directory".

- If you run the code directly from the command prompt / shell, the current directory will be the shell's current directory ... at the point that you ran the program.
- If you launch using a wrapper script, then the script *could* change the current directory before starting the program.
- If you launch from an IDE, then the IDE determines what the current directory will be.
- And so on.

To avoid this problem, use an absolute pathname.

It would also be instructive to figure out where that file was actually written.  On Windows you could try using the Search tool.  On Linux, the `find` command is a good choice; e.g.

```
  $ sudo find / -name properties.properties | less
```

... and wait.

---

Note that flushing and closing are not necessary in this particular example.  You are using a `FileOutputStream` which is not buffered.  However, if you wanted to do that, your code would need to look like this:

```
File file = new File("program.properties");
try (FileOutputStream fileStream = new FileOutputStream(file)) {
    write(fileStream, "username=max");
    write(fileStream, "score=12550");
    write(fileStream, "level=5");
    fileStream.flush();
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    System.out.println("Could not write file");
}
```

Note that the `fileStream` is implicitly closed because we declared it as a "resource" following the `try`

Comment: Ugg. Ok So embarrassed. You were exactly right I was looking in the wrong place. I'm looking in the output pane in Netbeans when I should be looking for the actual file in the Java project. Thanks so much for all you guys help!

Answer (score 1):

There is no error or exception in your code. The snippet actually created the file. Try testing the src by giving a test path.

```
File file = new File("C:\\Test\\test.txt");
```

The above modification created the file properly. And as was mentioned, you can use `fileStream.flush();` too.

Comment: I am not sure I understand the fileStream.flush(); code. Where do I put this code? Sorry, I'm a beginner so if you could clear this up a little more that would be great.

Comment: After the line write(fileStream, "level=5");. You can add fileStream.flush();

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Does the problem have to do with the "Working Directory" in the configuration options? Again I am a beginner so I don't know some of the terms listed by Stephen C. Sorry but I am a little lost. Any more info that y'all can give me would be most appreciated.

Comment: *"Does the problem have to do with the "Working Directory" in the configuration options?"* - Yes.  Current directory and working directory are synonyms.